# Convert string into proper format

Tags: encoding, character, quotes

I have added some text in DB containing curly quotes . So need to change the character encoding which changes curly quotes and similar different style symbols into normal quotes and symbols.

Sample as shown below :

Issue as shown below: Hi This is “text“
Required as per this: Hi This is "text"